# Solving $x^2 - 16 x+55> 0$ for $x$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Solving $x^2 - 16 x+55> 0$ for $x$

my work

$$(x-11)(x-5) > 0$$

then  x >11 and x > 5

is that correct ???

Comment: Nope.  Consider $x=0$.  The thing to remember here is that positve $\times$ positive $=$ positive and negative $\times$ negative $=$ positive.  But positive $\times$ negative $=$ negative.  Also $0$ $\times$ anything $= 0$.

Comment: what do you mean ???

Comment: Plug $x=0$ into your original inequality.  It works.  But it's neither $>11$ nor $>5$ so your guess at the solution was incorrect.

Comment: **Hint:** For $u,v\in \mathbb{R}$, $uv>0$ if $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^+$ or (in the "exclusive" sense) $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^-$.

Comment: No.  There are two possibilities.  Both x-11 >0 and x-5 >0 *OR* x-11 < 0 and x-5 < 0.  If x-11 > 0 an x-5 > 0, then x >11.  If x-11 <0 and x -5 < 0, then x <5.  So either x >11 or x <5.

Comment: If you're a beginner, drawing a graph is okay. However, as you gain mathematical maturity, it should be intuitively clear that the quadratic is concave up (positive leading coefficient) and hence is positive everywhere except between the zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Draw out the parabola $y=x^2-16x+55$ , using a graphics calculator [image]

We can clearly see that when $x>11$ and $x<5$ the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: not me , I voted up , thanks

Comment: As a side note , when doing these type of inequalities. I suggest drawing a graph out. It makes things much easier to identify :)

Comment: @user155971 If you found this answer helpful or answered your question. Consider "ticking it"

Comment: Certainly is not worth a down vote but graphic isn't proof and won't teach you anything and won't help you for anything with more than single variable functions.  Still this does show the answer.

Comment: @dydxx How did you draw this graph? :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul desmos graphing calculator. Search it up on google :)

Comment: @fleablood The graphic *is* a proof and the way I probably would have solved it would be to recognize this as a concave up quadratic and figured out its roots.  I.e. I would have mentally drawn out the picture.  Yes there are other ways of finding the solution set of this inequality but I think this illustrates a method that OP *should* be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $f(x)=x^2-16x+55=0$ gives $x=5$ and $x=11$ as the points  where the curve cuts the $X-$ axis. Now, it just remains to check the sign of $f(x)$ in the intervals $x<5$, $5<x<11$ and $x>11$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the first part of your argument is right

But Carefully introspect the case that 2 negative numbers when multiplied also gives a positive number number

I recommend using the wavy curve method to check your solution to  the above inequality

$\quad x\quad \in \quad (-\infty ,5)\cup (11,\infty )$